# Datarow ends up with wrong or lost data

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, datarow

I'm **scraping** twitter tweets, I launch multiple backgroundworkers and they do the following:

```
For x as Integer = 0 to 5
    Dim BGW As New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler BGW.DoWork, AddressOf TweetGrab
    BGW.RunWorkerAsync(tweeturl)
Next

Public TemporaryRows As New List(Of DataRow)
Private Sub TweetGrab(tweeturl as String)
    'some html stuff here

    Dim ImageUrl as String = twitterImage.Attributes("src").Value
    Dim ThumbnailUrl As String = ImageUrl & ":small"

    Dim DataRowTemporary As DataRow = DataTable1.NewRow()
    DataRowTemporary("ImageUrl") = ImageUrl 
    DataRowTemporary("ThumbnailUrl") = ThumbnailUrl 
    DataRowTemporary("Checked") = False

    'I detect the error even here

    TemporaryRows.Add(DataRowTemporary)
End Sub
```

Later on, I do stuff with the TemporaryRows. I loop over the rows and check if they meet some conditions.

The problem is that `DataRowTemporary("Checked")` ends being DBNull and `DataRowTemporary("ThumbnailUrl")` is completely different than `ImageUrl` even though I specified `Dim ThumbnailUrl As String = ImageUrl & ":small"`

This happens in about 2/10 cases. I would guess it has something to do with background threads but I don't have any ideas how to solve it. I can reedit the fields after the error occurs, but I would like to prevent the error from occurring in the first place.

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe. If you modify the same List from multiple threads, there you have it. Use a thread-safe container. Maybe `ConcurrentBag<T>` (better with Tasks instead of BackGroundWorker(s)).

Comment: @Jimi But the error appears before TemporaryRows.Add(DataRowTemporary), so it has nothing to do with the list as far as I see. DataRow values have a problem.

Comment: You're accessing a number of objects created elsewhere and then accessed concurrently by multiple threads. You can `Lock` (`SyncLock`), use containers of the Concurrent namespace or both. You should pass all existing object (that don't represent UI Controls and that are not modified by more than one thread) as the  `object` argument of the BackGroundWorker's `RunWorkerAsync(Object)` method overload. Anything else ends up in the same way you have reported. I didn't notice `DataTable1`, which is probably another object that shouldn't be modified or used to create other objects concurrently.

Comment: @Jimi DataTable1.NewRow() doesn't modify the table as far as I know, and that's the only thing shared between them. Error appears while assigning values to datarow columns, before adding datarow to public list, and way before adding datarow to datatable.

Comment: Yes, you're using all non-thread-safe objects to perform concurrent operations on and with these objects.

Comment: @Jimi Documentation says it's ok to concurrently read the DataTable, does NewRow() write something? DataTable1.NewRow() is the only thing in BGW, I do the rows.add synchronously on main thread. SyncLock appears to have solved it (I locked the table), didn't have any errors yet in the last few minutes.

Comment: Now, if you change your `TemporaryRows` in a `ConcurrentBag` (or `ConcurrentDictionary`, or `ConcurrentQueue` what fits better), you're probably ok, from what I can see here.

Comment: @Jimi I haven't found a parallel writing replacement for DataTable so I'll just stay with SyncLock. Make an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Pass the DataTable as the `Object` argument of `RunWorkerAsync([Object])`. I'll post something as soon as I can.

Comment: @Jimi I had an idea, what if I were to make a new datatable with same schema for each of the threads, do stuff to them, then later on merge them into my main datatable, that way there should be no problem since each of them will be using their own table.

Comment: Why don't you use a `ConcurrentDictionary(Of Integer, Object())`, where the Integer value is a progressive value you can [Interlocked.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment) (see the example there, note the `Lock()`) and the `Object()` is the array of objects you can add to a DataRow when you `DataTable.Rows.Add([Object()])`, so you don't need to pass the DataTable to the BGW and you get back, when each thread completes, a Dictionary with the data needed to add a new Row to your DataTable and you also have a Progress to report.

Comment: @Jimi Constructing the row ItemArray makes things more complicated, like this I can simply do Row("ColumnName") = Something. Is there anything to gain doing it that way compared to simply merging the background thread tables back into main thread one? Also, with simple integer that makes keeping the ordering of data dificult, I would need a list of ConcurrentDictionarys then. Again adding more complexity. My way I simply change 2 lines, instead of DataTable1.NewRow(), I create new table above it and use that for new rows. Later on instead of adding rows to my datatable, i merge tables.

Comment: You can do whatever you want (possibly using, in threads, objects that are built for that). I'm just suggesting other ways. To add a Row you simply `[DataTable].Rows.Add(Object())`, where `Object()` is a Value of a **single** `ConcurrentDictionary`. Its Key can also be used, as described, to ReportProgress. When the `ConcurrentDictionary` is filled (because all Threads are finished), you can add all the Rows in a single loop. Unless you need to show each Row when one is ready. For that, you can use the  `RunWorkerCompleted` event, passing the last Integer increment (Key of the Dictionary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was changing the collection when its being accessed by other threads (in parallel).
You can not do add/remove in parallel, the collection must be locked in order to not get strange errors.

```
SyncLock TemporaryRows 
     TemporaryRows 'Add/Remove
End SyncLock
```